# SQL: ANSI Subquery join

Tags: sql

I'm practising subquery in Snowflake (it supports common SQL queries). I stuck and cannot get the result I want.

Data

```
INSERT INTO members (memid, surname, firstname, address, zipcode, telephone, recommendedby, joindate) VALUES
(12, 'Baker', 'Anne', '55 Powdery Street, Boston', 80743, '844-076-5141', 9, '2012-08-10 14:23:22'),
(21, 'Mackenzie', 'Anna', '64 Perkington Lane, Reading', 64577, '(822) 661-2898', 1, '2012-08-26 09:32:05'),
(6, 'Tracy', 'Burton', '3 Tunisia Drive, Boston', 45678, '(822) 354-9973', NULL, '2012-07-15 08:52:55');
```

I want to get each member's name, member id, recommender's name and recommender's id.

My code

```
with recommender as (
select distinct concat(t1.firstname, ' ', t1.surname) recommender
        , memid recommender_id
    from "EXERCISES"."CD"."MEMBERS" t1
where exists (select surname from "EXERCISES"."CD"."MEMBERS" t2
              where t1.memid = t2.recommendedby)
)
, member as (
select 
    distinct concat(firstname, ' ', surname) as member,
    memid,
    recommender,
    recommender_id
from recommender 
left join "EXERCISES"."CD"."MEMBERS" t3 on recommender.recommender_id = t3.recommendedby 
) select * from member
order by member;
```

My output
[image]

Noticed that Burton Tracy is missing from the output because she doesn't have any recommender. I want to keep her data in the output. How should I rewrite my code?

Thank you

Comment: the first query (the most upper one) will be unable to bring even one row, since there's no data through matching condition by `t1.memid = t2.recommendedby`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you are using CTEs for this...? Or subqueries, for that matter.

Getting the person who recommeded a member is not more than a LEFT JOIN:

```
select
  concat(m.firstname, ' ', m.surname) as member,
  m.memid member_id,
  concat(r.firstname, ' ', r.surname) as recommender
  r.memid recommender_id
from
  members m
  left join members r on r.memid = m.recommendedby
```